# simplexml_load_file() with a variable

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm currently having an issue with simplexml_load_file(); my xml path is a url, that is rendered as a variable

```
$xurl = "domain/pathto/myfile.xml"; //  This is actually a variable that returns the entire URL to where my xml file is -- this will change from file to file


$xmlpath = parse_url($xurl, PHP_URL_PATH); // to get the path of my xml file ex. /pathto/myfile.xml 

$xmlpath = mb_substr($xmlpath, 1);  // returns pathto/myfile.xml
```

here is where my problem is, when I put it into :

```
simplexml_load_file($xmlpath);
```

In my function, I get nothing appearing from the XML file

However, in my same function if I change it to

```
simplexml_load_file("pathto/myfile.xml");
```

My function works fine.

I did an echo on $xmlpath and it returns the pathto/myfile.xml just fine.

```
<?php echo $xmlpath; ?> // returns pathto/myfile.xml
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Phil

```
echo strcmp("pathto/myfile.xml", $xmlpath)
```

returns a 0.

Comment: Are you totally sure the paths are the same? `echo strcmp("pathto/myfile.xml", $xmlpath)`. Also, you should enable `display_errors` and set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` in your `php.ini` file whilst developing. `simplexml_load_file` should trigger a warning if it fails

Comment: with that code, I'm returning a 0.

I don't have control over the php.ini unfortunately.

Comment: Ok, `0` means they are the same. Pop this at the top of your script (but remove it when you've finished developing)... `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks I get this error:"

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity

Comment: A quick search suggests that error generally means the file doesn't exist at the path specified. Try prefixing the path with the current script's directory, eg `simplexml_load_file(__DIR__ . $xmlpath)` (assuming the XML file is relative to your PHP script)

Comment: Forgot to add, if you're prefix with `__DIR__`, don't strip the leading forward-slash

Comment: xml file is uploaded to a different directory 

eg: my page is domain/dir/dir/dir/

My xml file is here
domain/uploads/myfile.xml

Comment: thanks Phil, I was able to fix it!